# find the number of occurrence of letter in a txt file using python

Tags: python

I need to read the letter from a .txt file and print the number of occurrence in txt file. so far i have been able to print the content in one line but having issue with the count, can someone please guide.

```
infile = open('grades.txt')  
content = infile.read() 
for char in content:
        print (char, end=' ')
```

this will read the letter from the txt file but i am not able to count the occurrence.

using below counter gives me 1

```
print (char.counter(char))
```

Comment: well, why should it give you anything else? `char` contains a single char, so obviously its count will be `1`.... you need to count the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for this

```
with open('grades.txt') as f:
    print(Counter(f.read()))
```

Example

> this is a test that has letters

Output

```
Counter({'t': 7,
         ' ': 6,
         's': 5,
         'a': 3,
         'h': 3,
         'e': 3,
         'i': 2,
         'l': 1,
         'r': 1})
```

Or to only include letters

```
from string import ascii_letters
with open('grades.txt') as f:
    print(Counter(i for i in f.read() if i in ascii_letters))
```

**Edit**
Without the use of any other libraries, the manual way to do the same thing as above:

```
from string import ascii_letters
d = {}
with open('grades.txt') as f:
    for letter in d.read():
        if letter in ascii_letters:
            if letter in d:
                d[letter] += 1
            else:
                d[letter] = 1
```

If your file looks something like

> A A+ B B- B B+ B+ A A- B+

Then the modification to the above code would be

```
d = {}
with open('grades.txt') as f:
    for grade in d.read().split():
        if grade in d:
            d[grade] += 1
        else:
            d[grade] = 1
```

Comment: we are not allowed to use counter yet, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. Hopefully your professor will ask you to explain your work.

```
grades = open('grades.txt').read().split()
for grade in sorted(set(grades),
                    key=lambda x: ord(x[0])*3-('+'in x)+('-'in x)):
    print ('{} students got {}'.format(grades.count(grade), grade))
```