# count letter from txt file in python

Tags: python

Files contain below letter. 
A A- C F C C B- B A A A- B B+ B+ B+ C C- B- A A A F. I need to read the file and get the below output.

```
6 students got A
2 students got A-
3 students got B+
```

and so on, so far i am able to go through the file but i am not able to count it from the sting, can some one please guide me.

```
infile = open('grades.txt')  
content = infile.read() 
for char in content:
    print (char, end=' ')
```

i get the output as below

A   A -   C   F   C   C   B -   B   A   A   A -   B   B +   B +   B +   C   C -   B -   A   A   A   F

Can someone please guide me how i can count the occurance.

thanks.

Comment: Use a split() to place values into a dictionary with the grade and the count.

Comment: Your classmate [asked this same question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32851098/find-the-number-of-occurrence-of-letter-in-a-txt-file-using-python)

Comment: is it `A+` or `A +`?

Comment: its A+ and A-. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like a homework problem I'll just give a hint.

```
c=Counter("A A- C F C C B- B A A A- B B+ B+ B+ C C- B- A A A F".split())
c.most_common()
[('A', 6), ('C', 4), ('B+', 3), ('B', 2), ('F', 2), ('B-', 2), ('A-', 2), ('C-', 1)]
```

Comment: They cant use `Counter`. Check the comment of his classmate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32851138/742269

Comment: If you want to give a hint, make it a comment and not an answer.

Comment: Why all this negativity?  Code in comments are not easy to read. There is no information in the question that he/she cannot use Counter, which is the most idiomatic way to solve this problem.

Comment: @karakfa I agree with you about the point about the Counter. I disagree with providing an answer that is self-proclaimed to be incomplete.